# How do i add an external CSS file as well as CSS in the HTML file?

Tags: html, css

Ok so i have been writing HTML for a few months now. But this is my first real full webpage. For a ltitle background, i am creating a webpage for my business. It is going to be very in depth. I cannot however, figure out how to use two CSS files or sources. I need one to be inside the actualy HTML page file, and also be able to use the external CSS file. Is this possible? Here is some of my code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #aboutUs {
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-left: 25px;
        top: 18px;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }
</style>
```

That is at the top  of the page ^^

```
<head>
    <!-- Cheange Title of Webpage below -->
    <title>DTSU - Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
```

and that is in the header ^^

```
<p>
    <div id="mainNavD">
        <a href="home.html" id="home">About Us</a>
        <a href="aboutUs.html" id="aboutUs">About Us</a>
        <a href="services.html" id="services">Services</a>
        <a href="support.html" id="support">Support</a>
        <a href="contactUs.html" id="contactUs">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="information.html" id="information">Information</a>
        <a href="sponsored.html" id="sponsored">Sponsored</a>
        <a href="reviews.html" id="reviews">Reviews</a>
        <img src="pictures/mainNavBar.jpg"/>
    </div>
</p>
```

and that is what needs to be formatted with the infile CSS. While the rest is going to be handled by the external CSS.

How do i make the two cooperate?

Here is the whole file, not including the css

```
<style type="text/css">

#aboutUs { 
    z-index: 100; 
    position: absolute; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left:25px; 
    top: 18px; 
    margin-right: 25px; 
}

#services {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#support {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#contactUs {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#information {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#sponsored {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#reviews {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

</style>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <!-- Cheange Title of Webpage below -->
        <title>DTSU - Home</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Div Buttons for Pages -->
        <p>
            <div id="mainNavD">
                <a href="home.html" id="home">About Us</a>
                <a href="aboutUs.html" id="aboutUs">About Us</a>
                <a href="services.html" id="services">Services</a>
                <a href="support.html" id="support">Support</a>
                <a href="contactUs.html" id="contactUs">Contact Us</a>
                <a href="information.html" id="information">Information</a>
                <a href="sponsored.html" id="sponsored">Sponsored</a>
                <a href="reviews.html" id="reviews">Reviews</a>
                <img src="pictures/mainNavBar.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </p>
        <!-- Header and Logo Combo -->
        <div id="headerD">
            <img src="pictures/header.jpg" />
            <div id="logoD"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have, should have worked.  In what way did it not work?

Comment: I'm not sure you've grasped the concept of how a browser parses the webpage it downloads...

Comment: i have it looking right but the links will not move to the right places

Comment: You might want to head over to MDN and learn a bit more before you continue what you're doing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply two different stylesheets to the same page by including each file separately, like this

```
<head>
    <!-- Cheange Title of Webpage below -->
    <title>DTSU - Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet1" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet2" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
```

Keep in mind that if you define different styles for `ul` elements (for example) in each stylesheet, the styling from stylesheet2 will overwrite the other.

Answer (score 1):

Place your style inside of the actual HTML instead of before it.  Also, you can use `@import` on the first line of the `<style>` if you want to make it prettier.

```
<head>
...
<style type="text/css">

    @import "stylesheet.css";

    #aboutUs {
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-left: 25px;
        top: 18px;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }

  .... other style rules ....

</style>
...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need 2 different CSS files in this case. If you just add css to the div block with id mainNavD it will only apply those styles to that div block. That is the purpose of adding ID's to your html tags, so that you can uniquely identify them.

You could also use inline style and just add the style in the html file directly. Just google "html inline css" and read up on that.

Comment: I really don't like the second half of that answer.  It's a true statement, yes, but inline styles vs. centralized rules are like the rotary phone vs. e-mail.  Just taking large steps in the wrong direction.

Comment: Yes I agree inline styling is not the best way to do it, but being that it is another option (even it is a bad one) I felt I should maybe mention it.

Comment: Understandable.  And not worthy of a downvote so I gotta just leave him to decide best practices from here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The `<style>` tag should be inside the header although having it at the top of the file works ok for me in Chrome. Try this:

```
<head>
  <!-- Cheange Title of Webpage below -->
  <title>DTSU - Home</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <style type="text/css">
    #aboutUs { z-index: 100; position: absolute; color: white; font-size: 24px; margin-left: 25px; top: 18px; margin-right: 25px; }
  </style>
</head>
```

And you should be ok. Otherwise, please post your whole file.

Comment: i shared the whole file now